# Deploying Tabular cube to Azure Analysis services

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-data-tools, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to deploy our cube to Analysis services. However it is giving us a permissions issue error as shown below:

[image: Deployment error]

I am getting the and setting the servername from azure portal and setting it in properties in SSDT as follows:

[image]

[image]

Also I was reading and it seems that Analysis services uses Windows Authentication to deploy and you can set this permission by connecting through SSMS. However when trying to connect through SSMS i was having another issue to connect which I am posting as a separate question. The link is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Authentication with Azure Analysis Services is still quite fiddly.

Here is what we do:

1. Install the latest SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). By latest I mean including previews [Currently at SQL SSMS 17.0 RC3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-release-candidate).
2. Install the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools (also the RC).
   [Currently at SQL SSMS 17.0 RC3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-release-candidate)

Then, clear out any cached credentials by navigating here:

```
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\AADCacheOM
```

[You can find more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-release-candidate)

Answer (score 0):

AAS Security is slightly different.  There is a specific place to add admins that differs from other PaaS in Azure.

[image]